# Laravel deploy in Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 14.04.5 OS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My public DNS in AWS EC2 is xx.xx.xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com . I have configure server, mqsql, phpmyadmin. 'public_dns_url/phpmyadmin' is working fine. I have cloned my laravel app repo in 'var/www/html/laravel_app'.

I gave 777 permission to my /storage and /bootstrap. Default index.html in 'var/www/html/index.html' is opening when i click in my public DNS. I can see my laravel app all directories when url is 'public_dns/laravel_app'. But when url is 'public_dns/laravel_app/public' its giving me HTTP Error 500 always. " The xx.xx.us-west2.compute.amazonaws.com page isn’t working

xx.xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 "

my laravel_app/public/.htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

my document root in etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf is

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

my etc/apache2/apache2.conf file is

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: check the error log `/var/log/apache2/` and check what's inside to give 500